# Globally Accessible Access Queries & Macros

Tags: vba, ms-access

I work with data exported to me in one-time "disposable" MS Access databases. The Access database always has 4 tables: table1, table2, table3, and table4. The first step is to design a query that creates a table 5 based on an inner join between table 1 and table 2. The second step is to design a macro that exports table 1, table 3, table 4, and table 5 each to their own Excel workbook. The third step is to run the macro. I can obviously import the "local" query and macro objects from a access database that already has them, but I am looking for recommendations for a quicker, more efficient way using Access/Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a few words:

1) Create the table with `SELECT INTO`:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.FieldName, T2.ID, T2.FieldName INTO [T5]
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID;
```

2) Export each table with [DoCmd.OutputTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Access-VBA/articles/docmd-outputto-method-access) method (VBA) or [ExportWithFormatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197066.aspx) macro action:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "YourTableName", acFormatXLSX, [File Path]
```

Lastly it's up to you how to run the above, through an [AutoExec](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-macro-that-runs-when-you-open-a-database-98ba1508-dcc6-4e0f-9698-a4755e548124) macro which runs when you open the database or a button on a form.

Hope this helps.